# How can I install and set up reaction commerce on windows?

Tags: e-commerce

I like to use reaction commerce, I am using a windows pc I need to set up my pc for development, can u tell guys tell me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard as you think:

Here's the doc to guide you through installation.

[Installation Guide](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/development/installation)

You need to install,

- Chocklatey
- Meteor
- Node.js
- NPM
- Reaction CLI

That's it.

You can always find the windows equivalent commands on internet.

Comment: Did this answer help?